# VMware Graphics Card Installation

Tags: vmware

If I use VMware ESXI can I take advantage of a good graphics card?

If so would i need the card installed on the server or client and which drivers etc are needed... Also is it possible to use any card?

I know there's some compatible cards.  This is for a small lab.

Comment: You understand that ESXi is an OS, so for any VM  being managed by the host to see the GPU, it would have to be installed on the server right?

Comment: Yes, I have it installed on a machine and am using the vSphere client. Can a VM running make use of a locally installed graphics card on a client?

Comment: Read my first comment

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you may be referring to just a general gaming gpu or something a little more dedicated towards esxi per link below?

http://www.nvidia.com/content/cloud-computing/pdf/nvidia-grid-datasheet-k1-k2.pdf

Using ESXI with pass through it is possible.